# how to include CC and BCC in email using Go

Tags: go

How to add CC and BCC on my email function in Go.

Here is my code

```
err := smtp.SendMail(
 "smtp.zoho.com",
 587,
 config.Email_id,
 config.Email_password,
 []string{email_to},
```

Answer (score 5):

That depends on which mail library you're using.  But the short version is:  Just add the `Cc:` and `Bcc:` headers as usual, same as you do for any other header, such as `Subject:` or `To:`.